# Binding single NSCell to multiple values

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscell

I've already killed a day on this subject and still got no idea on how could this be done in a correct way.

I'm using `NSOutlineView` to display filesystem hierarchy. For each row in the first column I need to display checkbox, associated icon and name of the file or directory. Since there's no standard way to make this, I've subclassed `NSTextFieldCell` using both SourceView and PhotoSearch examples, binding `value` in IB to `name` property of my tree item class though `NSTreeController`. I'm using `drawWithFrame:inView:` override to paint checkbox and image, forwarding text drawing to `super`. I'm also using `trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:` override to handle checkbox interaction.

Everything was fine up until I noticed that once I press mouse button down inside my custom cell, cell object is being copied with `copyWithZone:` and this temporary object is then being sent a `trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:` message, making it impossible to modify check state of the original cell residing in the view.

Since the question subject is about binding, I thought this might be the answer, but I totally don't get how should I connect all this mess to function as expected. Tried this:

```
[[[treeView outlineTableColumn] dataCell] bind:@"state"
                                      toObject:treeController
                                   withKeyPath:@"selection.state"
                                       options:nil];
```

but didn't succeed at all. Seems like I'm not getting it.

May this be a completely wrong way I've taken? Could you suggest a better alternative or any links for further reading?

---

**UPD 1/21/11**: I've also tried this:

```
[[[treeView outlineTableColumn] dataCell] bind:@"state"
                                      toObject:treeController
                                   withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.state"
                                       options:nil];
```

but kept getting errors like "[<_NSControllerTreeProxy 0x...> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key state." and similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to do what I needed by binding columns's `value` to `arrangedObject`'s `self` (in IB) and overriding cell's `setObjectValue:` so that it looks like:

```
- (void) setObjectValue:(id)value
{
    if ([value isMemberOfClass:[MyNodeClass class]])
    {
        [super setObjectValue:[value name]];
        [self setIcon:[value icon]];
        [self setState:[value state]];
    }
    else
    {
        if (!value)
        {
            [self setIcon:nil];
            [self setState:NSOffState];
        }
        [super setObjectValue:value];
    }
}
```

Actual `state` change is performed within another class, connecting its method to cell's `selector` (in IB) which I call using

```
[NSApp sendAction:[self action] to:[self target] from:[self controlView]];
```

from cell's `trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:`. This another class'es method looks like this:

```
- (IBAction) itemChecked:(id)sender
{
    MyNodeClass* node = [[sender itemAtRow:[sender clickedRow]] representedObject];
    if (node)
    {
        [node setState:[node state] == NSOnState ? NSOffState : NSOnState];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You bind a table (or outline) column's value, not an individual data cell's state. The data cell's object value is set to the current row/col's value then drawn so you don't have potentially thousands (or millions?) of cells created for no good reason.

Further, you want the tree or array controller's *arrangedObjects*, not its selection.

Bind the *column's* value to the tree controller's *arrangedObjects* as the controller key, and "state" as the model key path in IB; or @"arrangedObjects.state" in code as above.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant talking about `value`-`name` binding in the first place: I already have `arrangedObjects.name` bind to `value` of the outline column, so I can't bind it to `arrangedObjects.state` at the same time (and there's no `state` binding in the column I can make use of). How's that possible?..

Comment: *Oh!* Sorry about that! I don't believe that's possible with a check box button cell. I'm pretty sure you have to use a separate column for the check box button cell itself (with no title) if you want to use Bindings.